# How do you iterate through a CheckboxGroup in Java?

Tags: java

Can you iterate/loop through all checkbox controls that have been added to a CheckboxGroup? If so, how can this be done? If not, what is the purpose of the CheckboxGroup?

Comment: To answer your first question, I don't think it is possible.

Comment: -1, `what is the purpose of the CheckboxGroup?` - read the API description for the method. It tells you what this class is used for.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if(c is CheckBox)
   {
   // Do work
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The below code may help-

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));  
 CheckboxGroup cbg = new CheckboxGroup();  
 add(new Checkbox("c1", cbg, ...));  
 add(new Checkbox("c2", cbg, ...));  
 add(new Checkbox("c3", cbg, ...)); 

foreach(Control check in this.Controls)
{if(check is CheckBox)
{
//increment i if checkbox
i++;  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this iterate through all controls in the app, rather than all controls in the CheckboxGroup?